# I want to create two new user type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, customization

In WordPress, I want to create two register user type: 1.teacher and 2. student.. means register as teacher and register as a student.

1. teacher registration is free and it posts his video, text etc..
2. student registration is not free but it's 6-month and 12-month subscription when a student is subscribed for this then student show the teacher's all post.

**Can you please suggest me in this how to create this type of registration and membership...**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it using `add_role` function.

There are three parameters in add_role function.

```
add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities );
```

**$role:** *Unique name of the role.*

**$display_name:** *The name to be displayed in WordPress Admin Panel.*

**$capabilities:** *Privileges that one can access.*

*Complete list of all capabilities can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities).*

**Step 2** **: add user roles dropdown in registration form**

```
//1. Add a new form element...
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );

function myplugin_register_form() {

    global $wp_roles;

    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ) {
       // Exclude default roles such as administrator etc. Add your own
       if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'Administrator', 'Contributor', ] ) {
          echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
       }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

//2. Add validation.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );

function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['role'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && trim( $_POST['role'] ) == '' ) {
         $errors->add( 'role_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a role.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );

function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
   $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST['role'] ) );
}
```

**Finally How to check if a user is in a specific role ?**

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //The user has the "author" role
}
```

Comment: [code]function myplugin_register_form() {

    global $wp_roles;

    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ) {
       // Exclude default roles such as administrator etc. Add your own
       if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'teacher', 'student', ] ) {
          echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
       }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}[/code]
this function give me syntax error...